# Return JSON object from MySQL query using json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

The question was long, so I had to shorten it.

Anyway, I currently have the following table with the following results.

What I am doing is the following:

1. Query all the answers associated to one question
2. Encoding it after storing it into an array

**This is my current query:**

```
$stmt = "SELECT questions.question_text, answers.answer_text 
   FROM     questions, answers, test
   WHERE    questions.question_id = answers.question_id
   AND      questions.test_id =1";

$result = $connection->query($stmt);
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

**This is the PHP:**

```
$encode = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $encode[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($encode);
```

Which gives me this output:

```
[
    {
        "question_text": "What is HTML?",
        "answer_text": "HTML is a Hypertext Markup Language"
    },
    {
        "question_text": "What is HTML?",
        "answer_text": "HTML is a Hypertext Markup Language"
    },
    {
        "question_text": "What is HTML?",
        "answer_text": "HTML is a food"
    },
    {
        "question_text": "What is HTML?",
        "answer_text": "HTML is a food"
    },
    {
        "question_text": "What is HTML?",
        "answer_text": "HTML is an Asynchronous language"
    },
    {
        "question_text": "What is HTML?",
        "answer_text": "HTML is an Asynchronous language"
    },
    {
        "question_text": "What is HTML?",
        "answer_text": "HTML is a styling language"
    },
    {
        "question_text": "What is HTML?",
        "answer_text": "HTML is a styling language"
    }
]
```

**This is the *desired* output with json_encode:**

```
"What is HTML?": {
        "1": "HTML is a Hypertext Markup Language",
        "2": "HTML is a food",
        "3": "HTML is an Asynchronous language",
        "4": "HTML is a styling language"
    }
```

What I am currently getting is multiple **single** objects with one of the answers within them but always the answer associated to it. I wish to make a single object with all of the answers in it and the question representing the object. I really hope this makes sense. I am probably way off in my logic, so please forgive me for that.

I tried playing around with the while loop but I couldn't get it to work. Can someone lead me the right way towards achieving my desired output?

Thank you.

Comment: do your questions have unique IDs ?

Comment: your desired output is neither a feature from `json_encode` nor mysql related functions. You have to reorganize your objects in `$encode` yourself.

Comment: Yes they do.

@Maximus2012

Comment: Are there multiple questions for which you want the json encoded outputs or do you want it only for 1 question ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 there are multiple questions for which I would like the encoded outputs. Meaning, each questions will be its own object with its values (answers) inside of it.

Comment: I think the answer by ficuscr should be helpful. Does that help? I am just trying to think if that approach will be helpful for the multiple question case or do you need nested database iteration for the multiple question case (first getting all the unique questions and then for each of those questions, getting all the answers)

Comment: I think a nested database iteration. I think it would be a very logical thing to do. Based on the question ID, get all of the answers associated to it. That sounds pretty right, but I wouldn't know how to encode it.

Comment: you need to figure out the right array first. Since your requirement is custom, directly encoding the output array would not help you much. You would need a multi-dimensional array as demonstrated by ficuscr's solution. I am just not sure if that approach will give you the exact output that you are looking for.

Comment: It was kinda obvious that HTML is a food. For Chrome, it tastes like candy and for Internet Explorer it tastes toilet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my query to the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT questions.question_text, answers.answer_text 
   FROM     questions, answers, test
   WHERE    questions.question_id = answers.question_id
   AND      questions.test_id =
```

The while loop to this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $encode[$row['question_text']][] = $row['answer_text'];
}
```

This gave me this:

```
{
    "What is HTML?": [
        "HTML is a Hypertext Markup Language",
        "HTML is a food",
        "HTML is an Asynchronous language",
        "HTML is a styling language"
    ]
}
```

Which I can now work with.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like just altering the array you are building out...

```
$encode = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $encode[$row['question _text']][] = $row['answer_text'];
}

echo json_encode($encode);
```

Comment: Not exactly what OP wants but this is good enough to provide a clear approach.

Comment: tbh question was so long I skimmed :)

Comment: This gives me an error. Doesn't output anything. I believe it should. I even removed the space from "question _text" and no luck.

Comment: @TiffanyLowe what is the error message that you are getting ?

Comment: Yeah, error message?  Suppose make sure `$row` is what I think it is in that loop...  Do you get the gist of what I am saying? Also make sure you used most recent, someone edited my answer a bit earlier and messed it up.

Comment: It's within the jQuery script itself.
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in jquery.min.js:4"

It is pretty weird, I'm looking into it.

Comment: This question definitely helped me do what I wanted WITH a little tweaking from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Change this bit:

```
$encode = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $encode[] = $row;
}
```

To (start at 1 I have added the $i, instead of just pushing it to the end of the encode array):

```
$encode = array();
$i = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $encode[$row['question_text']][$i] = $row['answer_text'];
   $i++;
}
```

And you should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use PHP to do extra processing.

Just use mysql  [Group By](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
$stmt = "SELECT questions.question_text, answers.answer_text 
  FROM     questions, answers, test
  WHERE    questions.question_id = answers.question_id
  AND      questions.test_id =1
  GROUP BY questions.question_id;"
```

Comment: This returns only one question.

Comment: Could you give me a brief explanation of your table structure