# Html form input sent, then stuck in php page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

My situation is as follow, i have a form input in a Jquery Mobile page, and i am submitting the form with no form button. I need the returned result from the php(it is in JSON) back in the html. But at the moment when i submit the search with pressing the enter button, it links to the php page, with the returned results and just stuck there, and not back in the html page. 
Thanks for your time!

Code:

```
$("#searchform").submit(function( event ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://test.com/App/searchtest.php",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log(data);
            $("#content").append(data);
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<form id="searchform" name="searchform" method="post"
        action="http://www.test.com/App/searchtest.php" data-ajax="false">  
    <input type="search" id="searchinput" name="searchterm"
        value="" data-mini="true" placeholder="Where?"/>
</form>
```

```php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

include 'connect.php';

$search = ($_POST['searchterm']);
$keywords = explode (" ", $search);
$columns = array("country","name");
$andParts = array();

foreach ($keywords AS $keyword){
    $orParts = array();
    foreach($columns AS $column){
        $orParts[] = $column . " LIKE '%" . ($keyword) . "%'";
    }
    $andParts[]= "(" . implode($orParts, " OR ") . ")";
}

$and = implode ($andParts, " AND ");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Listing WHERE $and ";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$output = array();

// fetch your results
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // add result row to your output's next index
    $output[] = $row;
}

// echo the json encoded object
echo json_encode( $output ); 

?>
```

Comment: Ben, please provide the `php` for us to look at. Also, check your browser console `network` tab to see the response from the server. It will most likely tell you what is going on

Comment: What do you see in the console (if any). Also include some `php` code

Comment: Ok, but the php is returning the JSON with no problem. But i updated it in the edit.

Comment: @Ben Look at your network tab in your debugger (usually hit `f12`), it will show the error

Comment: Nothing in console, because it is stuck in the php page that echoed back the result. nothing in the network tab as well, just says No requests captured.

Comment: Have you Google'd the answer yet?, I found something similar: [Return JSON object from MySQL query using json_encode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22104924/1762224). And here's another: [php json_encode mysql result](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3563464/1762224)...

Comment: You should try using PDO instead of MySQLi if you want to marshall objects from a database.

Comment: I have googled it, but i havent got a solution yet, the problem is, my php/html is ok when it is not a form(but pure Ajax request), when it is a submit form, i can't get the result back into the html. As the form is in the input, and i need to get the result back through an Ajax.

Comment: I removed the form input, and just used pure Ajax for Post and Get.It's ok for now.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to do what oskr suggests is to use `.preventDefault()` -

```
$("#searchform").submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://test.com/App/searchtest.php",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log(data);
            $("#content").append(data);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Ben the problem with your code is that you are sending the ajax request and submitting the form at the same time, which implies linking to the php page, reloading the page and thus cancelling the ajax success handler.
To avoid this you should **return false** which prevents the form submission, at the end of your submit event handler or calling `event.preventDefault`.
I hope this helps:

```
$("#searchform").submit(function( event ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://test.com/App/searchtest.php",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log(data);
            $("#content").append(data);
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @rm-vanda: And thats why i say "or calling event.preventDefault". I just provided the two ways you can prevent the default behavior of the submit